# In which case will sqlite executeInsert return -1?

Tags: android, sqlite

The documentation for executeInsert in the SQLiteStatement class say that:

@return the row ID of the last row inserted, if this insert is successful. -1 otherwise.

But it can also cast an exception if the query fails, so in what cases will it choose to return -1 instead of throwing an exception?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the return value is always given, and the exception is set in the connection. So you would have to check your return value and retrieve the exception yourself.

Comment: Why does the title mention `pgsql`?

Comment: That was a mistake. It should be sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have an `INSERT` statement that is valid SQL but that does not actually insert any record.
When using the [INSERT ... SELECT form](http://sqlite.org/lang_insert.html), the `SELECT` query might not actually return any records.

Comment: Aha, did not think of that.

Answer (score 0):

It will return -1 if you insert into a `VIEW`, for example:

```
CREATE VIEW Magic AS select * from Something;

CREATE TRIGGER Magic_Insert
INSTEAD OF INSERT ON Magic
BEGIN
    insert into Something_Else values (new._id, NULL)
    -- create another something that has the same ID, but without a roundtrip back to Java
    insert into Something_Connected values (last_insert_rowid(), new.name)
END;
```

and from Java

```
SQLiteStatement insert = db.compileStatement("insert into Magic(_id, name) values(?, ?);");
// bind and stuff
long rowid = insert.executeInsert();
```

Funny thing is that we need to `SELECT` to get the id of what we just inserted, so the roundtrip saving is quickly inverted, but there are uses when this is necessary.